# Storing and collecting double value in mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been struggling with this piece of code since Friday and I just can't get it to work, I want to store two double values to a table and the closest I got was losing the decimals on the values which on coordinates is not good(its way wrong on maps).

My store method looks like this:

```
   public bool saveLatLong(Double lat, Double lon, String mapID)
{
    bool worked = true;
    String myConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webbased"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    String strSQL = "UPDATE map SET Latitud = '"+lat+"' AND Longitud = '"+lon+"' WHERE ID = '" + mapID + "';";
    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = myConn;
    myCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (MySqlException myE)
    {
        worked = false;
        Console.WriteLine("It's all gone south!: " + myE.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
    return worked;
}
```

in debug the MySQL string looks ok I believe: `UPDATE map SET Latitud = '57,7141957471802' AND Longitud = '11,9798612594604' WHERE ID = '563-34';`

My get method looks like this:

```
   public void getCordinates(String mapID, out double latitude, out double longitude)
{
    double nlat = 0.0;
    double nlon = 0.0;
    String myConnection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webbased"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
    String strSQL = "SELECT Latitud,Longitud FROM cases WHERE ID = '"+mapID+"';";
    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = myConn;
    myCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
    try
    {
        myConn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            if (myReader.GetValue(0).Equals(DBNull.Value)) { nlat = 0.0; } else { nlat = myReader.GetDouble(0); }
            if (myReader.GetValue(1).Equals(DBNull.Value)) { nlon = 0.0; } else { nlon = myReader.GetDouble(1); }                 
        }

    }
    catch (MySqlException myE)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's all gone south!: " + myE.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
    latitude = nlat;
    longitude = nlon;
}
```

What ever I try I just get 0.0 as the result and I just can't figure out why, I believe I have tried everything and I can't get heads or tails on the problem. I suspect there is an issue with the getDouble commands I run in the get method but I don't know what else to do.

I appreciate any idea or insight as to what the problem is why I am not being able to get hold of the values in the db.

Comment: they are described as Double but since mysql dont have double they should be floats, i suspect.

Comment: Try replacing the commas with periods.  MySQL may not be understanding the international format.

Comment: It stores ok with . in the double but when I collect it's still 0.0 value for some strange reason :/ Thanks for the help Gordon!